# How to run deepfreeze command line using command prompt in c#

Tags: c#, windows-services, deepfreeze

i am working with services using C#, and for some stuff i need to get deepfreeze state of the station (frozen or thawed), for this found this on [Faronic's documentation](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/400099/Faronics-Deep-Freezer-Professional-5.html?page=30#manual) , when i use the following command in command prompt : `C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\DFC.exe get /ISFROZEN`  it works and returns "THAWED." or "FROZEN." so i decided in my C# program to run a command prompt and redirect the Standard output to get the result of the command into a string variable , but it has not worked, i tried with any other commands and it works , i do not understand where is the problem.
there is the [DFC.exe download link](https://www.pconlife.com/download/otherfile/142880/9c8e872bb5e1aa5ad6074b4cb0d35d95/) if it does not exists ( complete the captcha and click to download)
It is my third day on it so i need help .. thank's for everyone , there is sample code :

```
string pathDf = @"C:\WINDOWS\syswow64\DFC.exe";
string cmdline = string.Format("{0} get /ISFROZEN ", pathDf);
string msg = "";
if (File.Exists(pathDf))
{
   Process cmd = new Process();
   ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
   startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
   startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
   startInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
   startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   cmd.StartInfo = startInfo;
   cmd.Start();
   cmd.StandardInput.WriteLine(cmdline);
   cmd.StandardInput.Flush();
   cmd.StandardInput.Close();
   cmd.WaitForExit();
   Console.WriteLine(cmd.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
   Console.ReadKey();
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

the command still not works .. but i found another way to get deepfreeze state , using registry key

```
private static string GetDeepFreezeState()
    {
        string result = "";
        try
        {     
            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Faronics\Deep Freeze 6");
            if (key != null)
            {
                Object o = key.GetValue("DF Status");
                if (o != null)
                {
                    result = o.ToString();                      
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)  
        {
            //react appropriately
            FilesUtilities.WriteLog(ex.Message,FilesUtilities.ErrorType.Error); 
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Maybe it will help someone.
On the other hand i still not able to run deepfreeze command line on my C# program, if someone has an answer , please help...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get Deepfreeze state using registry key

```
$path = 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Faronics\Deep Freeze 6'
$Key = 'DF Status'
$State = Get-ItemPropertyValue -path $path -name $Key -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

if ($State='Frozen') {Echo "Deepfreeze is currently Frozen"} else {Echo "Deepfreeze is currently UN-Frozen"}

pause
```